# How to clear the cache of applications scanned on Android O (API 26)?

Tags: android

Does anyone know about clearing the cache on android 8.0? I am having problems clearing the cache.

I reference it on git and run android <6.
Link: 
https://github.com/Vanderclin/Cleaner/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vanderclin/cleaner/model/CleanerService.java

I want it to run on android O (API 26). Who knows please help me thanks.

Comment: talking about Android 6, it is probably related to runtime permissions. Check which permissions does this code require (check in manifest), and then cross-check which of them require to be requested in runtime

Comment: #Vladyslav MatviienkoThanks for your answer but I'm looking for them to work on android 8.1

Comment: `I reference it on git and run android <6` what about Android 6? Does it work on it?

Comment: I have run successfully. I am currently stuck in android 8. I have consulted on many webs but there is no solution yet.